# Is there an efficient way to compute resizing of the multi-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, image-resizing, scikit-image, opencv, memory-efficient, python

I am trying to resize (increase the size of np array) for 3 dimensional image array `(60000,28,28) --> (60000, 227,227)`. i.e. increase the 2nd and 3rd two-dimensional np array's size. It consumes my entire 32 GB ram for ~5  mins. At the end of 5 mins, the resizing is complete but even after the completion of resizing, it doesn't free up and keeps consuming the entire RAM memory unless the python application is forced closed. Is there any efficient way to resize `(60000,28,28)` into `(60000,227,227)` np array?

```
x_train_resized = np.zeros( shape = (60000,227,227) )

for i in np.arange( x_train.shape[0] ):
    x_train_resized[i] = skimage.transform.resize( x_train[i,:,:], output_shape= (227,227) )
```

I also tried with cv2 as:

```
cv2.resize( x_train[each_sample,:,:], dsize= (227,227) ) # for all 60,000 arrays
```

which took about 2 mins (much faster than skimage.transform.resize). However, the RAM memory didn't free up similar to previous case even after completion of the computation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default `np.zeros` gives you floats, which are 8 bytes. So your data is [about 24.7 GB](https://www.bing.com/search?q=60000*227*227+*+8+bytes&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=60000*227*227+*+8+bytes) already. If you are feeding these to a neural network, consider converting the batches only.

Comment: yup thanks, got it!